# Assigning nested attributes to build_object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is their a way to create this hash not to loop?

```
 {"0"=>{":comment_id"=>"52"}, "1"=>{":comment_id"=>"53"}, "2"=>{":comment_id"=>"15"}}
```

Output:

```
[{":comment_id"=>"52"}, {":comment_id"=>"53"}, {":comment_id"=>"15"}]
```

So it can perform:

```
@article = Article.new(article_params)
@article.build_comments([{:comment_id=>"52"}, {:comment_id=>"53"}, {:comment_id=>"15"}])

@article.save
```

Comment: can you please try below line of code.
@article.build_comments([{":comment_id"=>"52"}]).build_entity

Comment: The question is not so clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use, **`object.values`**

**`object = {"0"=>{":comment_id"=>"52"}, "1"=>{":comment_id"=>"53"}, "2"=>{":comment_id"=>"15"}}`**

**`object.values`**

**`=> [{":comment_id"=>"52"}, {":comment_id"=>"53"}, {":comment_id"=>"15"}]`**

To convert keys to symbols,

**`object.values.map { |x| x.class;x.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.gsub(':','').to_sym] = v; memo} }`**

o/p:

**`[{:comment_id=>"52"}, {:comment_id=>"53"}, {:comment_id=>"15"}]`**

Comment: @on-the-way, just use `.values` method.

Comment: Is their a way to make it as ` [{:comment_id=>"52"}, {:comment_id=>"53"}, {:comment_id=>"15"}]` removing double qoutes on the key?

Comment: `object.values.map { |x| x.class;x.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.gsub(':','').to_sym] = v; memo} }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
a = {"0"=>{":comment_id"=>"52"}, "1"=>{":comment_id"=>"53"}, "2"=>{":comment_id"=>"15"}}
res = a.keys.map{|k,v| a.delete(k)}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: isn't that effectively a loop?

Comment: map function is far better than loop.

Comment: it uses iteration ... it's a loop .. what do you mean by it's better than a loop?